# Mock new Function() with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, google-cloud-platform, mocking, jestjs

I'm having trouble trying to mock a module with a constructor

```
// code.js
const ServiceClass = require('service-library');
const serviceInstance = new ServiceClass('some param');
exports.myFunction = () => {
  serviceInstance.doSomething();
};
```

And the test code:

```
// code.test.js
const ServiceClass = require('service-library');
jest.mock('service-library');
const {myFunction} = require('../path/to/my/code');

test('check that the service does something', () => {
  // ????
});
```

It's not like the Documentation example [Mocking Modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) because you need to instantiate the module after importing it. And isn't either like Mocking a Function.

How could I mock this `doSomething()` function while testing?

For reference, I'm trying to mock `@google-cloud/*` packages here. And I have a few projects that could take advantage on this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to mock the whole module first so that returns a jest mock. Then import into your test and set the mock to a function that returns an object holding the spy for `doSomething`. For the test there is difference between of a class called with `new` and a function called with `new`.

```
import ServiceLibrary from 'service-library'

jest.mock( 'service-library', () => jest.fn())

const doSomething = jest.fn()
ServiceLibrary.mockImplementation(() => ({doSomething}))
```

Comment: Life saver! ;) that's been fast. Thank you very much. I was getting a bit frustrated with it already.

Comment: Life saver! ;) for me also

Comment: You can find more information about this approach and others in the Jest documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter

Answer (score 8):

Following [@andreas-köberle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52860839/621058) solution I was able to mock `@google-cloud/bigquery` like so:

```js
// mock bigquery library
const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
jest.mock('@google-cloud/bigquery', () => jest.fn());
const load = jest.fn(() => ({'@type': 'bigquery#load_job'}));
const table = jest.fn(() => ({load}));
const dataset = jest.fn(() => ({table}));
BigQuery.mockImplementation(() => ({dataset}));

// mock cloud storage library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
jest.mock('@google-cloud/storage');
const file = jest.fn(name => ({'@type': 'storage#file', name}));
const bucket = jest.fn(() => ({file}));
Storage.mockImplementation(() => ({bucket}));
```

I'm leaving this here as a reference in case someone else googles something similar. But to make it clear, thats just a particularization for [@andreas-köberle answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52860839/621058)