# Jest : mock constructor function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I'm having trouble trying to mock a constructor Function.

Here is the main class that I want to test

```
// main.js

import { Handler } from './handler/handler.js';
var lh = new Handler(windowAlias, documentAlias);
   // rest of code
```

Here is how my Handler function looks. Im trying to mock this

```js
//handler.js
export function Handler(windowAlias, documentAlias) {
  this.windowAlias = windowAlias;
  this.documentAlias = documentAlias;

  this.attachEventListners = function(globalSet) {
    // do something
  };
}
```

And the test code:

```
// main.test.js
   import { Handler } from 'handlers/handler'

   describe('main script', () => {

       it('test handler', () => {
            jest.mock('handlers/handler', () => jest.fn())
            const mockEventListner = jest.fn()
            Handler.mockImplementation(() => ({mockEventListner}))

            //call main.js

            expect(mockEventListner).toBeCalledTimes(1);
})
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859389/mock-new-function-with-jest) stack overflow and tried  but now Im getting error like  _handler.Handler is not a constructor on the line that does new Handler(). How can I mock the new Handler call when its a constructor function

Comment: Why don't you just use a mock implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `./handler/handler.js` module and `Handler` class manually.

E.g.

`main.js`:

```js
import { Handler } from './handler/handler.js';

const windowAlias = 'windowAlias';
const documentAlias = 'documentAlias';
var lh = new Handler(windowAlias, documentAlias);
```

`handler/handler.js`:

```js
export function Handler(windowAlias, documentAlias) {
  this.windowAlias = windowAlias;
  this.documentAlias = documentAlias;

  this.attachEventListners = function(globalSet) {
    // do something
  };
}
```

`main.test.js`:

```js
import './main';
import { Handler } from './handler/handler.js';
jest.mock('./handler/handler.js', () => {
  return { Handler: jest.fn() };
});

describe('64382021', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    expect(Handler).toBeCalledWith('windowAlias', 'documentAlias');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64382021/main.test.js
  64382021
    ✓ should pass (6ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.093s, estimated 10s
```

Comment: how is this possible, wouldn't the constructor be called before the test has a chance to mock it?

Comment: "Jest will automatically hoist jest.mock calls to the top of the module (before any imports)", see https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports